# Getting values from soap xml response

Tags: android, soap, xml-parsing

I want to get values differently from this Soap Object response

```
anyType{Id=101;Name=Nitin;Salary=100000';}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your Object into SoapObject

```
SoapObject userObject = (SoapObject) res1.getProperty("data");
   if (userObject != null) {
     User user = new User();
      user.setId(userObject.getProperty("Id").toString());
      user.setName(userObject.getProperty("Name").toString());
      user.setSalary(userObject.getProperty("Salary").toString());
   }
```